# How should I interpret this sampler?

Tags: simulation, random-generation, bernoulli-distribution

Assuming $\theta$ and $d$ are given and the following proportionality exists,

$$P(\psi)\propto\prod_{i=0}^{100} \theta^{\psi_{i}}\times id^{1-\psi_{i}}\Rightarrow$$
one can assume that $\psi $ is Bernoulli distributed with the following form,
$$\psi_i\sim Bernoulli(\frac{\theta}{\theta+id})$$

but then how should I sample $\psi$? Should I sample a $\psi$ for each $i$? Then how would I get to the final sample for $\psi$?

Comment: This is how I understand it... Could you provide reference for it and/or full quote describing it?

Comment: eq 36 and 37 of this http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~teh/research/compling/hpylm.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your equations correctly, it translates to the following procedure (as coded in R):

```r
u <- runif(101)                                # draw from uniform distribution
phi_i <- as.numeric(u < theta/(theta + 0:100)) # Bernoulli draw
phi <- prod(theta^phi_i * (d*(0:100))^(1-phi_i))
```

So you draw each `phi_i` from Bernoulli distribution with different probabilities depending on `theta` and `i` and then follow the deterministic procedure to calculate your outcome.

You can notice that Bernoulli random variable serves here as a shorthand to say *"take $\theta$ with probability $\tfrac{\theta}{\theta+id}$ or $id$ with probability $1 - \tfrac{\theta}{\theta+id}$"* since it has only $\{0,1\}$ values, so everything to their power will be either $1$ or it's own value.